# PDFBox: clipping text when writing to PDPageContentStream or PDPage

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, clipping

I am looking into options to layout a PDF document that must be very neat and accurate.

The document is a sort of report and displays data onto an existing background.
In some situation, the text is larger that the room it should fit in.

I would like to clip the text to the precise area it is allowed to take (this is not wrapping or "elipsizing" as the text is most of the times numbers).

Here is the effect I am looking for (this is an example, I am not looking into shortening the string, I want the string to remain untouched, but being actually clipped outside its allowed area).

[image]

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a path, e.g. with `PDPageContentStream.addRect()`. Then call `PDPageContentStream.clip()`. This will intersect the current clipping path with your path. Then draw whatever you want to be clipped.

Don't forget to put the whole thing between `saveGraphicsState()` and `restoreGraphicsState()` or your clipping path will become empty at some time, due to it being intersected again.

To verify that your clipping path is correct while developing, replace the `clip()` call with `stroke()` so that you can see where it is.

Comment: Hhmmm, I just saw that all `PDPageContentStream` clipping methods automatically executes a `n` for the path. Why that? Why disallowing stroking and/or filling simultaneously?

Comment: @mkl "It was always like that" :-) I don't see a need to change that, I've never seen the "W" with anything other than an "n" in PDFs I've looked at.

Comment: Thxs @TilmanHausherr, it worked like a charm. If I may, I am wondering why there are no high level functions in PDFBox. I assume that we all have to develop our own function to left align, right align, crop, justify text and the rest. I am surprised that it is not part of the kit. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't know why PDFBox is low level, I haven't been with the project since the beginning. Maybe Boxable can help, it is on top of PDFBox. We're a very small team, and there are so many things wished by users...